# VB.NET Application Performance Profiling Visual Studio 2019

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, performance

I am trying to identify a performance issue with my application which is written in vb.net 4.6.1
When tried using microsoft performance profiler. It was pointing to an external code but when tried to understand what was the external code. It became really difficult. Refer below image for reference.

[image]

---

Comment: Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols, tick "Microsoft Symbol Servers".  You can't make the OS faster without spending money, always good to know you're done.

Comment: For the record, if you're using VS 2019 then you're almost certainly writing your app in VB 16. The 4.6.1 is the version of the .NET Framework that you're targeting. The same VB version can target multiple .NET versions and the same .NET version can be targeted by multiple VB versions.

Comment: External code include functions that start and stop the app, draw the UI, control threading, and provide other low-level services to the app. If you are interested in them, you could check the call path of external code. [View external code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/beginners-guide-to-performance-profiling?view=vs-2019#view-external-code)